# XGBRegressor score method returning strange values

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

I've tried to use XGBRegressor's score method from the Python API and It's returning a result of 0.917. I am expecting this to be the r2 score of the regression.

However, trying r2_score from sklearn on the same package, it returns a different value (0.903)

```
xgbr.score(x_test, y_test) # Returns 0.917
y_pred = xgbr.predict(x_test)
r2_score(y_pred, y_test) # Returns 0.903
```

What's going on? I couldn't find any documentation on XGBoost's score method. I'm using v0.7

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you call `xgbr.score()` this code is actually called:

```
    ...
    return r2_score(y, self.predict(X), sample_weight=None,
                    multioutput='variance_weighted')
```

But when you are calling the r2_score explicitly, the default value of `multiouput` param is "uniform_average".

Try the below code:

```
r2_score(y_pred, y_test, multioutput='variance_weighted')
```

And you will get identical results.

Comment: Perfect! Great answer and explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You meant sample weight = None is replaced "uniform_average" and not multiouput param!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).